python / behave / playwright seems to get the wrong context.page if popups are encountered, how to fix this please?
Using Python, Behave and Playwright is getting the wrong context.page if there are popups. How to fix please ?
Environment.py
@async_run_until_complete
async def after_step(context, step):
    if step.status == "failed":
        screenshot_bytes = await context.page.screenshot()
        allure.attach(screenshot_bytes, name="screenshot", attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)

Page Object.py

    async def customer_help_link(self):
        async with self.page.expect_popup() as page1_info:
            await self.page.get_by_role("link", name="Help", exact=True).click()
            page1 = await page1_info.value
            await expect(page1.get_by_role("heading", name="help?", exact=True)).to_be_visible()

Was expecting context.page to have the most recently opened page or popup

This is unclear. Please describe your use case/goal and share complete, runnable code as a [mcve]. See how to format my posts?

@ggorlen - Hi, you want me to upload all the code ?
